# bold font on \SImath{} in figure captions

Tags: captions, siunitx

I would like to bold my figure captions which include `\SImath{300}{\basepair}`. When I bold the `\caption` of the figure, it will bold all words except my notation that is in `\SImath{}{}`. How do I get these to be bolded as well?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\SImath}[2]{\SI[parse-numbers=false]{#1}{#2}}
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.png}
    \caption{\textbf{Here I describe the figure and note \SImath{300}{\basepair} windows. The 300~windows in SImath do not show up bold.}}
    \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please add an example of small  but complete document (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem. Where is defined `\SImath`? So far your question is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for providing code fragment. However,  it is not of any help. We can't test it since we still don't know where is defined `\SImath`. So, please be so kind and extend your code fragment to complete small document as I already asked you in my first comment. Now there is no way to help you.so I can only suggest to close your question as "need details ..."

Comment: You have added an edit, but under a different account.  To merge two accounts, please ask  moderator to combine them.

Comment: I've updated your edit to make the example compilable rather than the fragments of code you had originally. This is the best way to help us help you.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Please, have you seen my advice into the chat?